# customURL scheme iOS open secret part of app

Tags: ios, url-scheme, custom-url

I have created my customURL scheme lets call it myapp://

I want to us a qr code to access an otherwise hidden screen in my app using the customURL 
myapp://secret

I have explored various tutorials but cannot get them to work.

I'm after code I can insert under didFinishLoadingWithOptions

something that says the customURL is myapp://secret now do this method any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which tutorials have you followed? What have you tried? Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm after code I can insert under didFinishLoadingWithOptions
>
> something
>   that says the customURL is myapp://secret now do this method any help
>   would be appreciated.

That's not quite how it works. You should write your `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` such that it returns YES if your app can open the URL, and then implement `-application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` to actually open the URL.